# Inherits from Anonymous Type T

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to inherits from an anonymous Type for example, I have some classes and interfaces like

```
public interface IFoo{
     int A { get; set;}
     string B { get; set;}
}

public interface IBoo : IFoo{
     decimal C { get; set;}
}

public class Foo: IFoo {...}

public class Boo: IBoo {...}
```

now I want to define a class that extends the existing classes by adding some new properties which is applied to all class in the same way :

```
public class Extended<T> : T where T: IFoo
{
    bool D { get; set;}
}
```

so as a result in case of `Extended<Foo>`, the properties inside the `Extended<Foo>` would be:

```
 public int A { get; set;}
 public string B { get; set;}
 public bool D { get; set;}
```

I know this will give compilation error:

> CS0689: Cannot derive form 'T' because it is a type parameter

but why this is not applicable? as long as I am putting constraints in the declaration

The current solution: I should create a class `ExtendedFoo` which implements `IFoo` and `ExtendedBoo` which implements `IBoo` , my concern is if there is a way or workaround to be able to define one generic class that inherits all these type of classes where they implement the interface Foo.

Hope my question is clear

Comment: No, it is not possible. The type system doesn't allow it. What are you trying to achieve by trying to do this?

Comment: Stick around for Default Interface Implementations and Extension Everything in [C# 8](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/A-Preview-of-C-8-with-Mads-Torgersen).

Comment: @mjwills I updated the question, I included already the current solution but it needs to do this for every class you have ( imagine you have something like 200+ entities) and `IFoo` is like to mark the entity that can be extended or not and it is in real not meant to have properties in fact. I believe that there should be such implementation in C#

Comment: @Enigmativity, I have tons of entities Models, I want to keep them clean without adding `IsDirty` for example and other properties that has nothing to deal with the nature of the `Model` itself, it just a `thing` to wrap the model but not to modify the actual model.

Comment: @Monah - Don't extension methods work for you?

Comment: @Monah - It sounds like you need multiple inheritance. (Which you can't do other than with interfaces.)

Comment: @Theraot Exactly what I am looking for, an extension class of an existing one

Comment: You can inherit classes `Foo` and `Boo` from a class `Extended` instead of inheriting a class `Extended` from classes `Foo` and `Boo`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to inherit from generic type parameter in C#. It is also not possible to inherit from anonymous type as a matter of fact, but that is a distinct concept (see [MS Docs Anonymous Types entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)).

C# generics work in a way where for `class Generic<T> {}` the compiler generates a single incomplete type `Generic<>` which is then used during runtime to generate code implementations and types (e.g. `Generic<string>`, `Generic<int>`, ...). The code implementations for reference types share the same generated code: `List<string>` and `List<object>` are distinct types but use same code. (The same also holds for value types of same size but that is irrelevant in this case as we are talking about inheritance.)

Your requirement is to have a generic type `class Generic<T> : T`. I could imagine there is a way of generating an incomplete type `Generic<>` from that. However, every type `T` can have distinct members, virtual method table, etc. Therefore a code for each `Generic<T>` instantiation would be required to be generated separately, in a manner similar to how C++ templates work.

And that is currently not possible with C# compiler. The reason for that is probably that no-one found the use-case so valuable to design the language solution, resolve all the conflicts with existing features, and implement it.

I would recommend you to reconsider your design. As soon as you start mixing generic types and capabilities (business logic), you're probably moving away from idiomatic C# anyway. I would love to further elaborate on that, but your question seems very much like [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    int A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
}

public class Extended<T> : IFoo where T : IFoo, new()
{
    IFoo foo = new T();

    public int A 
    {
        get { return foo.A; }
        set { foo.A = value; }
    }

    public string B
    { 
        get { return foo.B; }
        set { foo.B = value; }    
    }

    public bool D { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to use `Extended<Boo>` for example, I will miss the `C` property, What I am asking is like something that will wrap the object by a shell where anything under hood the shell can access the properties of the object without coding new properties.

Comment: Define a property `public object Tag { get; set; }` in a class to store data that is associated with the object.

Comment: Still doesn't meet my requirements, Suppose that you want to display `Extended<Boo>` in a `DataGridView` when you have a `Tag` property, ( you can't show the details of `Tag` unless you write some read properties inside of Extended that will read from the `Tag`, but `Tag` is changing from object to another. Or to use reflection to read the primitive properties inside of `Tag` which is the one I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're asking for, a generic class doesn't inherit nor implement the generic type, it only gives you the type in the variable T so that you can use it.

A work around would be to do something like:

```
public interface IFoo {
     int A { get; set;}
     string B { get; set;}
}

public interface IBoo : IFoo{
     decimal C { get; set;}
}

public class Foo: IFoo {...}

public class Boo: IBoo {...}

public class Extended<T> where T : IFoo
{
    T Foo { get; set; } // Work with this property
    bool D { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile (even when you edit out the `{...}`).

Comment: I forgot to remove the ": T", thats all.

Comment: This is actually the start of a monad definition. Like `Task<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `Nullable<T>`, etc.