# How to create a C# abstract proxy class for an interface where all interface methods are required on the proxy?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create an abstract proxy for several interfaces.  Obviously both a concrete proxy implementation and the concrete proxied class it 'fronts' must implement the same interface.  The proxy accepts the proxied class (to proxy to).  Ideally I wouldn't constrain the interfaces at all but I [don't believe C# allows constraining a generic type to being an interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).  As such, my sample below uses `IProxiableInterface` to enforce.

Here's some sample code that all appears fine except for this problem:

- Without the parent class, Rider complains "'T': type name expected"
- With the parent class, Rider says "'T': interface name expected".
- For both, the compiler says "error CS0689: Cannot derive from 'T' because it is a type parameter"
- Both of them allow the concrete proxy to fail to implement the interface.

```cs
abstract class AbstractProxy<T> : /*MonoBehaviour,*/ T // <-- Error: "'T': type name expected" or "'T': interface name expected"
    where T : IProxiableInterface
{
    protected T impl;

    public AbstractProxy(T impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }
}

interface IProxiableInterface {}

interface IFriendly : IProxiableInterface {
    string sayHi();
}

sealed class HiSayer : IFriendly {
    public string sayHi() => "Hi";
}

sealed class HiProxy : AbstractProxy<IFriendly> {
    public HiProxy(IFriendly impl) : base(impl) {}

    public string sayHi() => impl.sayHi(); // <-- _should_ be an error when omitted but not because the interface constraint is ignored
}

sealed class User {
    public User() {
        IFriendly friendlyToBeProxied = new HiSayer();
        IFriendly friendlyProxy = new HiProxy(friendlyToBeProxied);
        Console.WriteLine(friendlyProxy.sayHi());
    }
}
```

So it seems C# disallows this approach (which I learnt after typing all of this into StackOverflow and getting hinted with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617372/inherits-from-anonymous-type-t) :) ).

For now I've had to remove the constraint on AbstractProxy so it doesn't have to implement the interface.  As a workaround I've added an assertion to a factory method that takes an extra generic type indicating the type being built:

```cs
Assert.IsTrue(typeof(T1).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T2)), "T2 \"{1}\" must implement T1 \"{2}\" for {0}", go, typeof(T2), typeof(T1));
```

So what's <del>a better solution</del> The Right Way to solve this, please?

Comment: Only way it would work is as: `abstract class AbstractProxy<T>  : IProxiableInterface where T : IProxiableInterface {...`

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of scenario that requires meta-programming; specifically, you need to implement a specific interface *only known at runtime*, which isn't something you can express against a pre-compiled type. Typically, you would end up using `TypeBuilder` to create a new type at runtime, implementing the type you need, and then using reflection to inspect the interface you want looking for the members you need, adding *those* onto your new type (`MethodBuilder` etc), and writing an implementation (`ILGenerator`) that invokes whatever proxy logic you need (which may involve writing a constructor via `ILGenerator` that takes the proxy instance as a parameter and stores it in a field, then access the field in each method for the proxy step). You'd then create the *concrete* type, and store that somewhere as a cache (because all this `TypeBuilder` work is expensive). This is a *lot* of work! As a starting point: [here's the proxy emitter for protobuf-net.Grpc](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/master/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Internal/ProxyEmitter.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want your `AbstractProxy` to use composition rather than inheritance, so you don't need it to derive from anything:

```
abstract class AbstractProxy<T> where T : IProxiableInterface
{
    protected T impl;

    public AbstractProxy(T impl)
    {
        this.impl = impl;
    }
}
```

`IProxiableInterface` defines no behaviour so it seems that you are using it simply to constrain the generic types.

This would then be fine:

```
sealed class HiProxy : AbstractProxy<IFriendly>
{
    public HiProxy(IFriendly impl) : base(impl) {}

    public string sayHi() => impl.sayHi();
}
```